# How to disable cache on Django?

Tags: python, django, get, request

I have a problem with my first django app  and I can not find the solution.
I send this to my controller:

```
http://localhost:8000/fun1_get_data/?param1_qty=10
```

The controller:

```
@never_cache
def func1_get_data(request):
  result = request.GET['param1_qty']
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(result), content_type = "application/json")
```

Only return the same parameter...very easy...but doesn't work.Only works the first time after restart de server or 'save changes' on archive .py.

The first time OK:

```
http://localhost:8000/fun1_get_data/?param1_qty=10
10
```

And then....

```
http://localhost:8000/fun1_get_data/?param1_qty=999
10
```

panic!!

---

Extra: the template:

```
url(r'^func1_get_data/', controlador.func1_get_data)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use it like this:

```
@cache_control(max_age=0, no_cache=True, no_store=True, must_revalidate=True)
def view(request):
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to your Django project and open the urls.py file - Import the cache decorator

```
from django.views.decorators.cache import never_cache
```

Use it as function wrapper instead of view decorator

```
path('', include('home.urls')),
path('', include('blog.urls','blog')),
path('ajax/next-page/', never_cache(views.load_more.as_view()), name='next-page'),
```

It works for me hope so it also for you.